# Inserting a record into a Data Extension API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

How to insert a record into a Data Extension from a landing page using API?

The following is throwing an err msg:

> Error Message:    SetProperty only works for objects in the
>   ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL namespace. Object Type: System.String
>   Property Name: Name

```
%%[

SET @deRequest = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@deRequest, "CustomerKey", "TestCase91")  

SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @JobID)
AddObjectArrayItem(@deRequest , "Parameters", @lue_prop)


/* Execute the Retrieve */
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@deRequest , @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)  

IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF

]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

I've only started writing these ampscript object calls but there are a couple of things that I've noticed with your code.

1. Replace CustomerKey with the Data Extension's external key. It should look something like this: BAC65871-7E7E-4001-8D98-E6E853fdsfBB3AD.
2. Create an object called APIProperty before creating the name value pairs. Instead of Parameters, use Properties.
3. If your Data Extension has a primary key you must declare it with the word Key instead of Properties

The code might look something like this:

```
%%[

Set @subkey = _subscriberkey
Set @emailaddress = emailaddr

SET @deRequest = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@deRequest, "CustomerKey", "[externalKeyForTheDataExtension]")  

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @subkey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@deRequest , "Key", @lue_prop)

SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", @subkey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @lue_prop)

SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "EmailAddress")
SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @emailaddress)
AddObjectArrayItem(@deRequest , "Properties", @lue_prop)


SET @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
SET @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "PropertyName", "DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "SaveAction", "UpdateAdd")
AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions, "SaveOptions", @saveOptions)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@deRequest, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode, @updateOptions)

IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF

    ]%%
```

I found it really helpful to look at the code being generated in the Processing tab of a Smart Capture to work out how to write my own code.

Comment: Is this code working for you? I keep getting the following error:  Error Message: Invalid property name. Object Type: ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.DataExtensionObject Property Name: Key

Comment: A variation of this worked for me for my particular scenario. What are the data fields in your data extension? Can you list them and identify the ones that are primary keys?

Comment: SubscriberKey (Primary Key, Not Nullable) and EmailAddress (Not Nullable)

Comment: I have altered the code above to InvokeUpdate instead of InvokeCreate in case there is already a record with the same subscriber key in the data extension. This will add a record if one doesn't exist and update the record if it does. If this does not work then I'm all out of ideas :(

Comment: @wimpywombat I'm not sure why you're referencing `@de` instead of `@deRequest` in the second `AddObjectArrayItem()` function.

Comment: This post may be helpful: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64214/capture-customer-info-in-new-de-via-a-link/64348

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I generally insert a row into a DE using the API AMPScript functions.

There are two columns in my target Data Extension: `SubscriberKey` (Text, 100) and `Updated` (Date):

```
%%[

Set @subkey = "aspriggs@degdigital.com"
Set @updated = "2015-01-27"

SET @deObj = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@deObj, "CustomerKey", "TestDE")

SET @prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Value", @subkey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@deObj, "Properties", @prop)

SET @prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Name", "Updated")
SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Value", @updated)
AddObjectArrayItem(@deObj, "Properties", @prop)

SET @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")

SET @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "SaveAction", "UpdateAdd")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "PropertyName", "*")
AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions, "SaveOptions", @saveOptions)

SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@deObj, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode, @updateOptions)

IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF


]%%
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:sans-serif;">
      <br/>@subkey: %%=v(@subkey)=%%
      <br/>@ts_statusCode: %%=v(@ts_statusCode)=%%
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the output:

[image: DE update results]