# Capture customer info in new DE via a Link

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, web2lead, ssjs

Is it possible to capture customer information into a new DE by someone clicking on a link?

As an example: capture the email address in a new DE by clicking on a link ( Click on this link to Opt-in)?

Comment: Are you sending Emails through Salesforce activities ?

Comment: DE = Developer Edition?

Comment: Sorry for not bing clear DE = data Extension in ExactTarget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of the [UpsertData()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#UpsertData) AMPScript function.  This code would be in your landing page.  It'll read in a URL parameter named `sk` and write it to the `TestDE` data extension.

The data extension has two columns: `SubscriberKey` (Text 100, primary key) and `Updated` (Date).

```
%%[

    var @de, @sk, @num_filter_columns, @lookup_col_name, @lookup_col_value
    var @update_col_name1, @update_col_value1, @update_col_name2, @update_col_value2
    var @results

    set @de = "TestDE"
    set @sk = QueryParameter("sk")
    set @num_update_columns = 2
    set @lookup_col_name = "SubscriberKey"
    set @lookup_col_value = @sk
    set @update_col_name1 = "SubscriberKey"
    set @update_col_value1 = @sk
    set @update_col_name2 = "Updated"
    set @update_col_value2 = now()

    set @results = UpsertData(@de,@num_update_columns,@lookup_col_name,@lookup_col_value,@update_col_name1,@update_col_value1,@update_col_name2,@update_col_value2)
]%%
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:sans-serif;">
    @sk: %%=v(@sk)=%%
    <br>@results: %%=v(@results)=%%
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the output:

[image: UpsertData function output]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, but it's not the link doing the work, it would be the page the user goes to that does the work.

You could easily create a landing page that subscribes a user to a new list by passing the email to the page as a query string.

Comment: Thanks is it possible to do a one click opt in? could we append the email to the URL dynamically?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with ampscript

Comment: do you have any example you could share? i know how to do the query string part not not sure how to add the email address to a new data extension part

Comment: Im sure you can find ampscript functions to use on code.exacttarget.com. if you have some code not working share that and we can debug it

Comment: UpsertData function: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#UpsertData

Comment: Can also be done with the Add() SSJS function: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/

Comment: Thanks guys, when i create a url + Query string (?email=%%emailaddr%%) and add the upsertdata ampscript above the doctype!. how does this pull the emailaddr in to the data extension? i only want the email address to added, only if  the opt-in link has been clicked and not any others

Comment: The functions adam linked to will help. You will need to build a landing page to send the user to. Unfortunately i wont have time today to write the solution for you.